# How to make a multi-user system(windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, software-rec, multiple-users

I have an idea to use my pc to access my friend's pc's user remotely from home while he is using the other user on the his pc. How can I setup this multi-user system?

Answer (score 2):

Technically it would be a standard Windows feature, already built in: create two user accounts and use "Remote Desktop" to connect.

Unfortunately, the Windows 10 *license* does not allow more than 1 active user – while you can have multiple users logged in, the system will limit you to one user *connected* at a time. Connecting via Remote Desktop will lock out the console user and vice versa.

To have multiple connected users, you would need a Windows Server system and an apropriate number of Terminal Services user licenses (although 2 concurrent users are available by default).